# Pie chart not including all data

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl

I created Pie chart using [this example](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/pie.html) in official doc. Here is my code

```
1  pie = PieChart() 
2  labels = Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=5)
3  data = Reference(sheet, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_row=5)
4  pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
5  pie.set_categories(labels)
6  pie.title = "What did you like best about SKY Schools?"
7  sheet.add_chart(pie, "E1")
```

Here is the data in Excel and Pie Chart

[image]

The Pie Chart is not picking last data point: "The Golden Keys". I read documentation for [`Reference`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.reference.html) object, but could not understand what's causing the problem. In line 2 and 3, I tweaked max_rows value by 1 but it did not resolve.

Any help/ideas?

Comment: To include the 5th row, you need to set max_row to 6.

Comment: @Greg Thank you. I did that but it does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`titles_from_data=True` is used to specify that the first item of data (cell C1) is a title.

However looking at your screenshot, there is no title. Therefore you can either set it to false or not set the parameter at all.

**To re-create your screenshot:**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

from openpyxl.chart import (
    PieChart,
    ProjectedPieChart,
    Reference
)
from openpyxl.chart.series import DataPoint

data = [ 
    ['What did you like best about SKY Schools?', 'Games', 48],
    ['What did you like best about SKY Schools?', 'All of it', 36],
    ['What did you like best about SKY Schools?', 'Breathing', 25],
    ['What did you like best about SKY Schools?', 'Yoda', 23],
    ['What did you like best about SKY Schools?', 'The Golden Keys', 16]
]

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in data:
    ws.append(row)

ws.merge_cells('A1:A5')

pie = PieChart()
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=5)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_row=5)
pie.add_data(data)
pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = ws.cell(1, 1).value
ws.add_chart(pie, "E1")
wb.save("results.xlsx")
```

Comment: `titles_from_data=True` is the culprit. Thanks for the help.